# Can European Union Commissioners be members of political parties?

Tags: european-union

Can European Union Commissioners be members of political parties, or must they resile their memberships of such groups?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though they are not supposed to represent their country, EU Commissioners are politicians appointed by their respective national government and usually (nearly always) members of a political party.

Comment: You might give some examples.

Comment: What would be the point? You can literally pick any of them (only counter-examples I found in the current commission are Julian King and Maroš Šefčovič). I think the other answer is somewhat misleading by implying it's merely possible and failing to mention it's usually (nearly always) the case and highlighting an example.

Comment: Is there a distinction to be made between the nomination of a Commissioner by a member state and the appointment of that Commissioner to the role. If there is, does that mean the state nominates and the Commission President appoints?

Comment: @Ben Not sure what you mean exactly, might be worth asking as a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can. Just by picking a [random name](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/commissioners/2014-2019/oettinger_en) from [this list](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/commissioners/2014-2019_en), we found [the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BCnther_Oettinger):

> Günther Hermann Oettinger (born 15 October 1953) is **a German
>   politician and a member of the Christian Democratic Union** (CDU).